# Execute a remote command after sudo - su anotheruser in Rundeck

Tags: sudo, rundeck

I'm new with Rundeck and completely amazed with it and I'm trying to execute a job and my scenario is detailed bellow:

- Rundeck is configured with ssh password less authentication between node Server (rundeck server) and node Target (remote Solaris host)
  for user "master".
- In node Target I want to execute a script `/app/acme/stopApp.sh` with user `appmanager`.
- Normally when I need to run the script above I manually proceed with:

`ssh master@server`

`sudo su - appmanager`

or simply

```
ssh -t master@server
sudo su - appmanager
```

works without password and finally run (as appmanager)

`/app/acme/stopApp.sh`

But I don't know how can I reproduce these steps using Rundeck. I read in some previous 
messages that for each job line rundeck uses a new ssh connection, so the workflow bellow 
always fails for me with the messages:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Remote command failed with exit status 1

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Without this functionality I wouldn't be able to introduce a little DevOps
in my department. :-D

I read the user guide and admin guide but I couldn't find an easy example,
neither in this forum, to follow.

I will appreciate your help.

Rundeck version is 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your ssh login works without a password, you also need to configure sudo on your Target server so that it doesn't require a password.

Since you only need for the *master* user to be able to run commands as the *appmanager* user, you can handle this completely through sudo. In `/etc/sudoers` on Target, add:

```
master  ALL=(appmanager) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then your ssh command becomes:

```
ssh -t master@server 'sudo -u appmanager /app/acme/stopApp.sh'
```

If you need environment setup that is normally handled by the appmanager login shell, you'll need to source that setup explicitly. (And I would argue that the deployment environment setup should not be confined to a login shell anyway.)

More details on how to let one user run commands as another user are in a [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access) and the much denser [sudoers man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo su - appmanager
```

Tries to open a login shell, and therefore wants a real terminal. Remove the "-" to avoid this behavior. In the end, your command is going to look like

```
sudo su -c /app/acme/stopApp.sh appmanager
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me  after that the message bellow is showed: 

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

Password:

Comment: `echo MyFancyPassword | sudo -S su - MyFancyUser any_shell_command`