# How can I use sudo su - in Rundeck?

Tags: linux, ssh, automation, sudo, rundeck

I'm trying to run commands in RunDeck that require **sudo su -** without having to specify a username or password. I'm using OpenSSH as the Node executor.

When running sudo su - through Rundeck, I am asked for a password.

However, if I open an SSH session from my server to that remote node, and run sudo su -, it's passwordless.

I've set the username in RunDeck XML resource file as the same user that I SSH in that remote node as.

How can I run one or multiple commands using sudo su - (once at the beginning of my workflow) without having to enter a password?

I tried using JSSH and SSH only as my node executor. My SSH key are set as RSA, but I also try converting them as OpenSSH format.

The connection to my remote node with those SSH key works properly since the public key was added to the authorized keys.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to configure sudo on your Target node in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962949/10426011) to get it work on any ssh-related model source.

But if you want to configure the secondary password for sudo, OpenSSH Node Executor [doesn't support](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6116) that. That's possible by using [SSHJ](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/sshj-plugin#status) (out of the box on the latest Rundeck versions) or the [default SSH](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#secondary-sudo-password-authentication) node executor.